# Silverlight 404 on service with SSL enabled

Tags: wcf, silverlight, ssl

I've tried a lot of tips on this one but I cannot get it working. On the client I have:

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="[binding_name]">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="/[service_name].svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="[binding_name]"
                contract="[contract_name]"
                name="[endpoint_name]" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And on the server:

```
...<service name="[service_name]">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="[binding_name]"
              contract="[contract_name]"
              name="[endpoint_name]"/>
    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange"
              binding="mexHttpsBinding"
              address="mex" />
  </service><behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors><bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="[binding_name]">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType ="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>...
```

One potential clue is that when I navigate to https://[server_name]/[service_name].svc?wsdl, I see the location is correct on

`<wsdl:import namespace="http://[namespace]" location="https://[server_name]/[service_name].svc?wsdl=wsdl0"/>`

but incorrect on

`<wsdl:port name="[binding_name]" binding="tns:[binding_name]">
<soap:address location="http://[machine_name]/[service_name].svc"/>
</wsdl:port>`

Notice location="**http**://[**machine_name**]/[service_name].svc" Is that expected? If not, what could be the problem?

I've also made sure that [service_name] in the server configuration is the FQN of the service implementation. Everything worked as expected before I enabled SSL on the server and changed the security mode to transport, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my case was the fact that though the service_name in `<service name="[service_name]">` was the correct FQN of the service implementation, it did not match the Service attribute in the *.svc file. In that case it seems that WCF creates a default name for the endpoint, which is something like BasicHttp_service_name. That worked until SSL was enabled and was looking for the endpoint with a URL starting with https.

As for the machine_name issue, it was because I didn't set the host name for https in the IIS site bindings.